FluentUI: Capture KeyCode [Ctrl] + Mouseclick
I  am using FluentUI for Blazor WASM in version 4.10.3.
I want to check if they key [Ctrl] is pressed when clicking on an element with my mouse.
I registered builder.Services.AddFluentUIComponents(); in Program.cs and added <FluentKeyCodeProvider /> in my MainLayout.razror, all accoring to documentation: https://www.fluentui-blazor.net/KeyCode.
However I can only recognize if I press [Ctrl] with another key, e.g. [Ctrl] + [G]. A single [Ctrl] KeyDown isn't recognized. For example the following does not trigger, when just pressing [Ctrl]:
public async Task OnKeyDownAsync(FluentKeyCodeEventArgs args)
{
    if (args.CtrlKey)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("[Ctrl] was pressed.");
    }
}

How can I achieve to recognize if [Ctrl] is pressed, when clicking with my mouse (normal left click) anywhere on my page, e.g. on a div container?

Thank you for your sharing and I never though about it before. Accordign to the document you shared, it only provides a FluentKeyCodeEventArgs which I'm afraid we can't  get mouse click event from it at the same time. FluentKeyCode component is a new feature in FluentUI.Blazor v4.6 and it says it retrieves the KeyDown information when the OnKeyDown event is raised.

So that I try to find an event which could both contain ctrl key down event and mouse click event, and I get this one MouseEventArgs which is blazor built-in event arguments. Maybe this can be a workaround for you?

As @Tiny Wang mentioned in the comments, the blazor built in MouseEventArgs does the trick here.
While I can use FluentKeyCodeEventArgs for commands like [CTRL] + [Z]:
public async Task OnKeyDownAsync(FluentKeyCodeEventArgs args)
{
    if (args.CtrlKey && args.Key == KeyCode.KeyZ)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("[Ctrl] + [Z]");
    }
}

For mouse clicks the blazor native MouseEventArgs should be used, for example
<div style="background-color:blueviolet" @onclick="args => MouseClickTest(args)">Click me with [Ctrl]</div>

...

private async Task MouseClickTest(MouseEventArgs mouseEventArgs)
{
    if (mouseEventArgs.CtrlKey)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("[Ctrl] + mouse click");
    }
}

